# Optimized way to check if record is present in table 1. If not then check table 2, else return default value

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hive-query

Asked in an interview:
I have 2 tables, one table has records like `ID, Name, address`. `id(pk)` is from 1 to 10000000.

Another table has records from 10000001 to 20000000.

I have to check if a  particular ID is present in table 1 or table 2 and return corresponding result.

Because table size is big, have to think an optimized way to do this.

Comment: please provide more details. Are they mysql table or hive? You have to do via code or query?

Comment: @shaileshgupta This was in hive. and I was asked query for this. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

```sql
declare @ID BIGINT
SET @ID=10000000
IF EXIST(SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=@ID)
    SELECT ID,NAME,ADDRESS FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=@ID 
ELSE IF EXIST(SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=@ID)
    SELECT ID,NAME,ADDRESS FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=@ID 
ELSE
    SELECT @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas on top of my mind.

- In the hive, you can use map-side join which is much faster than usual join when 1 table is large and another is small. (here 2nd table being the id you are searching for)
- You can optimize in the way you store the data. Keeping the data sorted by id column, if such queries are frequent. A columnar format such as orc keeps track of the range of id in each file, resulting in such queries being faster.